# Autocomplete Form not loading from database

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flask

My autocomplete form works fine if I populate the list manually. However, If I populate from db the dropdown list does not populate.

HTML/JS

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
        <form method="POST"  action="/">
            <dl id="autocomplete" style="display:inline-block;"> . 
               {{render_field(form.search) }}
           </dl>
           <button id="searchbutton" type="submit" style="display: inline-block;"  class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" onclick="fetchlist(); return false;">Search</button>
        </form> 
</div>      


<script>
$(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source:function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON("{{url_for('autocomplete')}}",{
                q: request.term, 
            }, function(data) {
                response(data.cities); 
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            console.log(ui.item.value); 
        }
    });
})

function fetchlist() {
    if (document.getElementById('searchbutton').onclick) {
        document.getElementById('list').style.display = 'inline';
    }
    else document.getElementById('list').style.display = 'inline';
}
```

Flask

```
@app.route('/_autocomplete', methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    c, conn = connection()
    qry = "SELECT Distinct PhoneNumber FROM webappdb.posts"
    c.execute(qry)
    x = c.fetchall()

    cities= list(chain.from_iterable(x))
    #cities = [x for x in c.fetchall()]
    print(cities)
    '''
    cities = [
          "123",
          "12"]'''

    return Response(json.dumps(cities), mimetype='application/json')
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage():
    try:
        form=SearchForm(request.form)
        global d1
        d1 =""
        if request.method == "POST":
            s1 = form.search.data
            c,conn = connection()
            qry = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM posts WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE (%s)"
            c.execute(qry, s1)
            d1 = c.fetchall() 
            c.close()
            conn.close()
            print(d1)
        else: print('error')
        return render_template("index.html", data=d1, form = form)
    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

Ideally, i'd like a user to being typing and the autocomplete returns and filters data in the database. Once the user finds what they are looking for, it would pull information based on that person's phone number.

Comment: '''
    cities = [
          "123",
          "12"]''' Don't you have to return a dictionary? Meaning that the list cities needs to include dictionary rather than an element.

Comment: @Jessi no, if i return a list it works fine.